# Show nodes which have at least one relationship with specific labelled nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi !

I am currently trying to show via `Neo4j Browser` all nodes with a specific Label (Here named "Label1"), when each of them have at least one connection with 3 specific labelled nodes ("X","Y","Z"). I've tried the following query:

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
where a:Label1
and size((a)-->(b)) >= 1
and b:X
and b:Y
and b:Z
RETURN a,b, size((a)-->(b)) AS count
```

However, it returns me everything instead of only nodes with these labels. Did I made something wrong here ?

I've also Tried to exclude nodes with labels I don't want to see, like:

```
and not b:LabelX
```

But they still appear.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm assuming the :X, :Y, and :Z nodes are separate and not the same node, and that there are only one of each, you can get what you want with:

```
MATCH (a:Label1)
WHERE (a)-->(:X)
AND   (a)-->(:Y)
AND   (a)-->(:Z)
RETURN a
```

Comment: Great ! That's exactly what I looked for :-) Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-label

`a` must have label `User`

```
(a:User)-->(b)
```

`a` must have label `User` **and** `Admin`

```
(a:User:Admin)-->(b)
```

So,

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
where a:Label1
and b:X
and b:Y
and b:Z
RETURN a, b
```

Could be written as:

```
MATCH (a:Label1)-->(b:X:Y:Z)
RETURN a, b
```